# mail: Options MUST PRECEDE persons

Tags: linux, email, shell, unix, solaris

I am trying to send an email by specifying the from option using mail.

```
echo "This is the main body of the mail" | mail -s "Subject of the Email" 
recipent_address@example.com -- -f from_user@example.com
```

Whenever I try the above command I always get error as-

```
mail: Options MUST PRECEDE persons
```

And I didn't get any emails. Why is it so?

And I am running `SunOS`

```
bash-3.00$ uname -a
SunOS lvsaishdc3in0001 5.10 Generic_142901-02 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Comment: in addition to the answers below, you probably want to use `-r`, not `-f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** 
Your title indicates one thing, now I see you want to pass in who the sender is. Per quote from man page below, `-f` doesn't mean `from`.

Why do you need to do this, your mail client and sendmail will properly set your 'from' header? (and please answer this by editing your question, not as a comment below :-) ).

**end edit**

The reason you're getting the error message that you do get is that for almost all Unix commands (including `mail`) using `--` indicates to the program (mail) 'END OF OPTIONS'.

So your `-f` will not be processed as you expect. Why don't you do

```
echo "This is the main body of the mail" | mail -s "Subject of the Email" \
 -f from_user@example.com recipent_address@example.com
```

???

For the two mail(*) programs I could find man-pages for online, they both have similar use for the `-f` option:

```
 -f [file]       Read messages from file instead of  mailbox.
                     If no file is specified, the mbox is used.
```

So is that what you intend? And, to put it another way, your use of `-f user@example.com` doesn't seem to make sense unless you have mailbox files named like that.

IHTH